# Android box - soft bricked, but can boot Linux

Tags: linux, rom-flashing, smart-tv

**Introduction**

First of all I have quite old android box - Ferguson 3 TV. It's hardware based on platform very similar to MXQ/HD18Q with s805 processor. Stock rom based on Android 4.4 (not Android-TV). I was able to run LibreELEC Linux for this box in dual bot, or even from internal, so it is somehow compatible.

**Now what happend...**

I soft bricked it when trying to flash android custom rom from MXQ. The TWRP flashed just fine, and I flashed rom zip from this. After this procedure, neither system, not TWRP is not booting. After few tries I was able to flash LibrELEC to internal storage. I also booted Armbian (linux) from SD card. But recovery is still not bootable.

**What I want to do**

Is there any way to flash stock firmware from linux to unbrick the device? Or any other way? When I connect box to Windows PC, nothing happens, like Windows doesn't see it. So I think this booted linux is the only way I can modify the internal memory. I have stock firmware zip, from the Ferguson page. It is recovery zip, but contain inside `boot.img` and `bootloader.img`. The`/system` is just a folder. There are also `/recovery` folder which only contains some scripts to extract recovery from `boot`.

Any ideas how to save this box?

Comment: I tried Amylogic Burn Card Maker, but it doesn't boot. Linux does, but this utility doesn't.